# React js CSS modules doesn't find @keyframes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, keyframe, react-css-modules

I'm trying to use react css style-inline to animate my div, the goal it's using the keyframe rotation only on the corresponding CSS module(home.module.css), but it doesn't work.
Does everyone knows why seems like is the @keyframes never called?

> It works only when I put @keyframes in global.css

```js
import React from "react"
import classes from "./home.module.css"

export default function Home(){
  return (
      <div 
          className={classes.test} 
          style={{animation: rotation 20s linear infinite}}
      >
        Rotation test
      <div>
  )
}
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: #ffff
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call animation effect in `.test`:

```css
.test {
  background-color: #ffff;
  animation: rotation 20s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

And you don't need to add inline styling:

```js
export default function Home(){
  return (
      <div className={classes.test} >
        Rotation test
      <div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, I want to make the duration dynamically...

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by dynamic? Your code does not except any input